# Howto jquery Serialize formvalue

Tags: jquery, serialization

collecting data from formfields to append to the post script.

```
var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&company_name='+ company_name + '&adres='+ adres + '&zip='+ zip + '&city='+ city + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone + '&message=' + message + '&imgs=' ;
```

But the last value imgs can be multiple values added trough an ajax upload script and is generated dynamicly
 i created a hidden form field, but dont know how to pass the hidden form vars to the datastring, who can help me out here?

```
//Add uploaded file to list
                if(response==="success"){
                    $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html('<input name="image" class="img" type="hidden" value="mailatt/'+file+'" /><img src="mailatt/'+file+'" alt="" width="300" /><br /><p>'+file+'</p>').addClass('success');
                } else{
                    $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').text(file).addClass('error');
            }
```

Comment: have you tried this `var dataString = $("#testform").serialize();`

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery's [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) form:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
```